# How to reference a different cell each month?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to reference a different cell depending on the Month on p4. For example, the current Month is June, so C4 should be referenced on P4. On July 1st, D4 should be referenced on P4, then in August E4, in September F4, and so on.

[image: Snapshot of my google sheet]

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

`=HLOOKUP(text(now(), "mmmm"), B1:M4, 4, 0)`

Here is an example of it working. The order of months listed in row 1 do not matter:

[image]

Hope this helps!